# AutoCompleteTextView show all posible matches ie (Sao Paulo | São Paulo)

Tags: android, view, android-edittext, textview, autocompletetextview

I've got this `AutoCompleteTextView` in my activity, it's adapter is a list of cities, my problem is:

When I type a name like São Paulo, it shows the suggestion São Paulo, but if I type Sao Paulo (whitout the accent), it doesn't show nothing because the to the AutoCompleteTextView, `a != ã`.

How can I do so if i type in Sao Paulo, it suggests São Paulo?

Comment: check out this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33801067/modify-autocompletetextview-to-show-results-with-local-special-characters

Comment: Couldn't make it work